# When I use xctest to test my download function , it occurs this error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.1

An error occurred on the xpc connection:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.nsurlsessiond" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.nsurlsessiond}

I don't known what it is "service named" com.apple.nsurlsessiond??

Comment: In my case it's working with session default mode and failing with background one.

Comment: how to resolve the issue?

Comment: @djserva Yes ！Ths.

Comment: still seeing this issue